# Android Communication between Broadcast Receiver and MainActivity (Send data to activity)

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, broadcast

I've a simple Main Activity which has to stop till an SMS is received... How can I launch a method from the `MainActivity` within the `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()` Method?

Is there away with Signal and Wait? Can I pass something with a pending `Intent`, or how can I implement this communication?

Answer (score 10):

Communication from BroadcastReceiver to Activity is touchy; what if the activity is already gone?

If I were you I'd set up a new BroadcastReceiver inside the Activity, which would receive a CLOSE message:

```
private BroadcastReceiver closeReceiver;
// ...
closeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  //EDIT: receiving parameters
  String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("name"); 
  //... do something with value

  finish();
  }
};
registerReceiver(closeReceiver, new IntentFilter(CLOSE_ACTION));
```

Then from the SMS BroadcastReceiver you can send out this action:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CLOSE_ACTION);
i.putExtra("name", "value"); //EDIT: this passes a parameter to the receiver
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: Mhm...I'm registering the Receiver directly in the Manifest... and need to exchange Data's with the Receiver...

Comment: No problem. The data can be sent using Extras. i.putExtra("name", "value"); Only primitive types can be passed though.

Comment: Quick fix: `context.sendBroadcast(i);` it must use the BroadcastReceiver context to propagate the intent.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, I tried using intent but i was unsuccessful

The easiest way to use it would be using static methods and static variables

**MainActivity.java**

```
public static void stopsms()
{

/*
some code to stop the activity

*/

}
```

**SMSReceiver.java**

at the end call this function

```
MainActivity.stopsms();
```

It works amazing if your code does not affect when you use static methods and variables. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: is there a way I can access the mainactivity context from that static void function?

Comment: is this not dangerous, calling a static method on the activity? What if the activity doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with registering a second receiver within the activity, however, is that it will not be persistent like registering in the manifest... thus, although, this solution may work, will only work if the activity is running in background.

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy, use interface like that:

1) in your broadcast receiver create an interface.

```
public interface ChangeListener{
    public void functionWhoSendData(String type);
    public void etc();
}
```

and instantiate that interface in your broadcast receiver, use it:

```
public void onReceive(....
    String data=functionWhereYouReceiveYouData();
    ChangeListener.functionWhoSendData(data);
}
```

And in your activity, make it implements your interface

Comment: when I do that I get the ClassCastException. Apparently the context in the onReceive can't be cast to the interface.