# Simple MainActivity and BroadcastReceiver derived class communication Issue

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This should be very simple and I'm really not sure what is going wrong. I have created a `SMSReceiver` java class that basically receives messages and then gives them to my `MainActivity`. When the `onReceive()` function fires, the app crashes because it is having issues sending the data back to `MainActivity`. It has been throwing a `NullPointerException` on the `Zout()` call in `onReceive()`.

Here is the `SmsReceiver` class:

```
package ...; //you don't need to see my dumb package name.

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers;
    ArrayList<String> textMessages;
    private Activity mainAct; //our reference to MainActivity

    //very simple constructor
    public SmsReceiver() {

    }

    //this function is called in onCreate() in MainActivity to provide reference to MainActivity
    public void SetSMSReceiverActivity(Activity a){
        mainAct = a;
        //talk to our main activity
        MainActivity mainComm = (MainActivity)mainAct;
        mainComm.Zout("SMSReceiver initialized bro"); //this works just fine
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //THIS IS WHAT CAUSES ISSUES! This call to MainActivity does NOT work for whatever reason. Rude.
        MainActivity mainComm = (MainActivity)mainAct;
        mainComm.Zout("This message won't send"); //this does NOT work fine for whatever reason. Throws NullPointerException.

        //...more code down here that actually works!
    }
}
```

The function `Zout()` in my `MainActivity` is a simple print to `TextView` for debugging purposes. I will be using a function in `MainActivity` to receive the data once `onReceive()` stops being moody.

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. I haven't programmed in Java for a few years and I'm quite rusty. I have no idea why this isn't working. I'll be tossing out +1's to whoever can help!

Comment: There a few different ways you could go about this.  1) Use an interface to facilitate communication 2) Use a static method in the Activity 3) Use a separate BroadcastReceiver in the Activity that the SmsReceiver would broadcast to when it receives a broadcast.  There are some good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132425/android-communication-between-broadcast-receiver-and-mainactivity-send-data-to

Comment: Thanks @DanielNugent! I'm going to look into some alternate forms of communication now. Is there any explanation to why the function call to MainActivity works in one function but not the other? I'm puzzled :s.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you have not initialized your mainAct variable.

for onCreate(){}
you do initialize

```
mainAct = a;
```

but not for onReceive.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am setting the class-wide variable mainAct in SetSMSReceiverActivity() before onReceive is called. I'm sure there is a better way of getting a reference to MainActivity in onReceive() but I'm not sure what that is. I see the debug message "SMSReceiver initialized bro" but when onReceive fires I still get a NullPointerException :(.

Comment: I believe you have to use SetSMSReceiverActivity(Activity a) method within onReceive() method in order to set the value of mainAct.

I believe just having a setter method would not let you actually set the value...

You can just set it within onReceive as:

     mainAct = (A class you want)

to check if this is the reason why... if this works, then it might be that you have to call the setter within the onReceive method